# Libtorrent Logging through python bindings, possible?

Tags: python, bittorrent, dht, libtorrent

I noticed the Rasterbar/Libtorrent page mentions the possiblity of "verbose logging of the DHT protocol traffic"

http://www.rasterbar.com/products/libtorrent/building.html

Does anyone know if its possible to do with the python bindings?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

From what I read in the C++ source, compiling with dht logging just makes the library log into a file (dht.log), and there doesn't seem to be any API on top of that.

Now, you may want to take a look at the parse_dht_log.py file at the root of the source distribution of libtorrent - depending on what you want to do, this may get you started in parsing that log file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: yes, this is a build option, mostly intended to be used for debugging